# WiFi Transfer of Data from RPi to Smartphone without Internet

Tags: pi-3

I need some help. Is it possible to transfer data from a RPi +3B,
using WiFi to an Android or iOS smartphone?  There would have to be a two way communication between smartphone and RPi. There is no local internet available for miles and miles in desert.
I have nothing else to share at this point.

Comment: On android, you can create a "hotspot" - and connect the pi to it - however I'm not sure if the pi would be able to access the android device or vice versa, as the hotspot just allows an external device to use the android device mobile data for internet

Comment: If your phone is reasonably recent, just use WiFiDirect.  That is what it is for.